# Formula error - Column result based on multiple rows values

Tags: google-sheets

Known values:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tenant | Flat no. | Duration stayed | Energy consumed in flat |

To find out:

| E |
| --- |
| Energy consumed per tenant |

Condition:
I have to consider the unique value of column `A` as an identifier in order to avoid duplicate results/errors in calculations.

Example:
4 tenants `A2:A5` stay in the same flat `B2:B5`, they have consumed 85KW `D` over 30 days `C`

Simple Formula:
`=D2/SUM(C2:C5)*C2`.
Manual process as per every flat

Formula to automate:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,D2/SUMIF($B$2:$B$44,B2,$C$2:$C$44)*C2,"")
```

However this formula only works up to a certain range.  If I increase the range for column `B`, the result becomes incorrect.

[Link to Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TIKPWmSCmM1Dzy-71WbeFcwn5cvVbm6ih_-wfpMaCHE/edit#gid=2100307022)

[image: Ref. image-1]

[image: Ref. image-2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your data is that there are several groups of data by the same flat number in column `B`, while only one group of data should be considered at a time. For example, flat `102` appears not only on rows 6, 7 and 8, but also in rows 91, 92, 93, 94 and 95.

The formula below will match the desired results you show. It creates a "window" to data that spans ten rows above and below the current cell, and only includes flats with a matching flat number within that window:

```
=let( 
  flats, B2:B, durations, C2:C, consumptions, D2:D, 
  subset_, lambda(flat, 
    sum(filter( 
      durations, 
      flats = flat, 
      isbetween(row(flats), row(flat) - 10, row(flat) + 10) 
    )) 
  ), 
  map( 
    flats, durations, consumptions, 
    lambda( 
      flat, duration, consumption, 
      if( 
        isblank(flat), 
        iferror(ø), 
        consumption * duration / subset_(flat) 
      )  
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Hi doubleunary, 
First of all, Thank you!
This worked like a charm! 

Yes, they have common flat names in many cases which is why I wanted to find a way to consider the row in such a way that it could act as a unique identifier, in order to avoid miscalculations and give accurate results. 

I have updated the sheet link along with a column H, in which I used your code. I'm not good in coding but I understood the logic.

Just curious though, can the same be done through google sheet functions without line of codes?

Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: The formula is using plain vanilla Google Sheets spreadsheet functions. It is just formatted with newlines and indentation to make it more readable.